# Converting John Resig's JavaScript Templating Engine to work with PHP Templates

Tags: php, jquery, regex, templates, kohana

I'm trying to convert the John Resig's Templating Engine to work with PHP.

Essentially what I would like to achieve is the ability to use certain Kohana Views via a JavaScript templating engine, that way I can use the same views for both a standard PHP request and a jQuery AJAX request.

I'm starting with the basics and would like to be able to convert

http://github.com/nje/jquery-tmpl/blob/master/jquery.tmpl.js

To work with php like so...

```
### From This ###
<li><a href="{%= link %}">{%= title %}</a> - {%= description %}</li>
### Into This ###
<li><a href="<?= $link ?>"><?= $title ?></a> - <?= description ?></li>
```

The RexEx in it is a bit over my head and it's apparently not as easy as changing the %} to ?> in lines 148 to 158. Any help would be highly appreciated. I'm also not sure of how to take care of the $ difference that PHP variables have.

Thanks,

Serhiy

Comment: That's not an "ASP.NET" templating engine, it's a Javascript template system. It doesn't really have anything to do with ASP.NET.

Comment: Didn't know that... found it via an ASP article...

Comment: In either case how hard would it be to make it read a PHP template and act upon it the same it would on the JS template.

Comment: Well the point is that it works completely on the client side. In a way, php already *is* a template engine.

Comment: By the way is there a way to revise a question... I'll take away the ASP.NET part...

Comment: You could drop the data into Javascript variables and then let the client render the template, but since you know everything at page construction time anyway, why not just build the page with php?  (You can edit the question by clicking the little "edit" link.)

Comment: Thanks... kinda new... kept looking for it but couldn't find it... anyways my reason is so that I can load in cross-domain data via .js files, and render the data using the same views that they would be rendered with via PHP.

Comment: Presumably he has a need to bring templated content via ajax, most people will simplify examples. Im working on doing a similar thing with Spark template but in JS, obviously with a flat view model, simple extension methods.

Comment: Well, I don't know php so I can't say how you'd do that, exactly, and I'm not even sure it makes sense.

Comment: Here's a PHP template sample...  <li><a href="<?= $link ?>"><?= $title ?></a> - <?= description ?></li>    I just want the JavaScript to be able to go by <? instead of {% and accept $ in front of variable names... but my RexEx Skills aren't up to par to debug those errors.

Comment: What you're talking about doing seems like it'd be much harder than just altering the templates.

Comment: I know... which is why I'm asking for some help or some pointers so that I don't waste a lot of time embarking on this. But in the long run I see this as a positive/time-saving thing because I won't have to create duplicate templates, one for PHP one for AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Since I've gotten no pointers in how to do this all in pure JS I've thought of another method. Any advice or pointers on this method would be highly appreciated as well. I was thinking of writing my views in HAML using kohaml to parse them.

http://github.com/transphorm/kohaml

Then tweaking the kohaml interpreter a bit to spit out JS Templates for me as well. What do you guys think of tackling the problem that way?